# Link to my SE profile

Tags: support, hyperlinks, profile-page

I would be surprised if this *isn't* a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the answer here. Maybe I'm using the wrong words...

How can I create a link to my StackExchange account/profile to use on other sites? Something like the one on the left pane in [this blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called "flair", and you could find in your profile page for howto.